# installing django-remote-forms on pythonanywhere virtualenv

Tags: django, installation, pythonanywhere

I want to install django-remote-forms on [pythonanywhere](http://www.pythonanywhere.com) virtualenv
but it seems pip repo dose not include django-remote-forms
and also whene I upload the files on pythonanywhere host I dont have required premission
for installing using setup.py
if any one could help me

Answer (score 1):

You can install it directly from github:

```
pip install --user https://github.com/WiserTogether/django-remote-forms/archive/master.zip
```